# How to write a generator to a file in Python and then read that file to be parsed for meta data attribute values

Tags: python, json, io, generator

I am scraping Tweet data from the Twitter Streaming API and hoping to write the data to a file and then access that file to parse it for values.

The desired output data will contain thousands of tweets.

The data for a single scraped tweet looks like this:

```
"created_at": "Wed Oct 18 01:52:13 +0000 2017", "id": 920467522222198784, "id_str": "920467522222198784", "text": "RT @davidaxelrod: Hopeless. https://twitter.com/4guh7RZpSq", "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "truncated": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "user": {"id": 726973455325908993, "id_str": "726973455325908993", "name": "Just Merry", "screen_name": "jp_pgh", "location": "Pittsburgh, PA", "url": null, "description": "Tweets and retweets and retweets. Mostly politics, cuz you know, Trump. I'm really big in Belgium.", "translator_type": "none", "protected": false, "verified": false, "followers_count": 77, "friends_count": 276, "listed_count": 2, "favourites_count": 11354, "statuses_count": 5909, "created_at": "Mon May 02 03:15:53 +0000 2016", "utc_offset": -25200, "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "geo_enabled": false, "lang": "en", "contributors_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA", "profile_background_image_url": "", "profile_background_image_url_https": "", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/740007509218451456/PG9xh48Q_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/740007509218451456/PG9xh48Q_normal.jpg", "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/726973455325908993/1486181468", "default_profile": true, "default_profile_image": false, "following": null, "follow_request_sent": null, "notifications": null}, "geo": null, "coordinates": null, "place": null, "contributors": null, "retweeted_status":
```

As you can see, each tweet contains numerous attributes such as the date when the tweet was created, a unique id for each tweet, the text of each tweet, the screen name of the user who tweeted it, and so on.

I want to write each of potentially thousands of tweets to a file (presumably a json document?) and be able to access this file and parse values from the file.

For example, using the output file, I'd like too be able to create a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing the 'screen_name' who sent the tweet as a key, and the 'followers_count' for each screen name.

My script for scraping and writing the data looks as follows (the scraping works), but I know I think I am writing the data incorrectly:

```
import twitter
import io
import json
from oauth_mining_social_web_1_2 import oauth_login

q = 'politics'
print('Filtering the public timeline for track="%s"' % (q,))
twitter_api = oauth_login()
twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=twitter_api.auth)
stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track=q)

for tweet in stream:
    with io.open('{0}_newfile1.json'.format(q), 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(str(json.dumps((tweet, ','), ensure_ascii=False)))

        print(tweet)

def load_json(filename_prefix):
    with io.open('{0}_newfile1.json'.format(filename_prefix), encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return f.read()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Using the output file, I'd like too be able to create a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing the 'screen_name' who sent the tweet as a key, and the 'followers_count' for each screen name as the value. But I don't know how to do that. And before that, I don't know if I am correctly writing the tweet data to a file for successful parsing.

Comment: I'd suggest you use some example data and actually show the output of your code.  Show what's not working, and what the expected output should be.  Consider [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines for assistance.

Comment: Here's a link to some sample output code. https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive?ths=true

Comment: I read the data in as results_politics.  So I tried to access the first screen_name with: results_politics['screen_name'][0].  And the error I get is TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Looks like you're not collecting multiple values in `results_politics['screen_name']`. It'll be easier to help if you put all this in your post. But really, it sounds like you need to narrow down your exact question more. Try inserting print statements to figure out exactly what you're storing and if it's what you expect. Working with Twitter JASON can be frustrating at first, but most of the work just requires lots of debugging patience and methodical testing.